# Octopus Deploy: Enable SNI on IIS HTTPS binding?

Tags: iis-8, octopus-deploy, sni

We're using **Octopus Deploy** and its "**IIS web site and application pool**" process feature to deploy our ASP.NET MVC app to IIS. It's working great.

Now, we would like to enable **SNI** for the HTTPS binding. Octopus Deploy doesn't seem to provide a built-in checkbox for this. How could we customize the Octopus Deploy's IIS deployment so that the SNI is enabled automatically?

If it makes things easier, it's OK for us if Octopus Deploy automatically enables SNI for all the HTTPS bindings, we don't need a setting for it.

Comment: Nice! Are you using [AzureWebFarm.OctopusDeploy](https://github.com/MRCollective/AzureWebFarm.OctopusDeploy) (just remembering https://github.com/MRCollective/AzureWebFarm/issues/4)?

Comment: Yep, we're using AzureWebFarm.OctopusDeploy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't currently possible to do with the built-in IIS configuration feature; instead, you could use a custom PowerShell script (PostDeploy.ps1 in your package, for example) to make the appropriate changes. I've logged a work item here to add it when we next revisit IIS configuration:

https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Issues/issues/430

Comment: looking forward to this feature!

Answer (score 4):

For anyone still looking for a solution on this, at this time of writing, octopus now offers this exact feature on the "deploy an IIS Website step template, right on the bingings section, you can create https 443 bindings where you can specify a cert and check the "require sni" option, to automatically deploy certs per each virtual host.

[image: Add binding dialog]